# Kendo grid radio button not working when editable = true

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I had this kendo grid and I want to use radio button in `status` column. It bind the right value but when it come to editing seem it not working. Any idea why? Somehow it work fine if im not using `class="k-radio"`

[FULL DEMO HERE](https://dojo.telerik.com/odoleFUP)

```js
{ field: "status", title: "Status",
  template: data => data.status == "perc" ? "Percentage" : "Amount",

 editor: '<input data-bind="checked:status" class="k-radio" id="perc" name="status" type="radio" value="perc" >' +
         '<label class="k-radio-label" for="perc">Percentages &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>' +
         '<input data-bind="checked:status" class="k-radio" id="amt" name="status" type="radio" value="amt" >' +
         '<label class="k-radio-label" for="amt">Amount</label>'  

        /* work fine but I wanted to used kendo class */
        //"<input name='status' type='radio' data-bind='checked:status' value='perc' onclick=''>" +
        //"<label>Percentage</label>" +
        //"<input name='status' type='radio' data-bind='checked:status' value='amt' onclick=''>" +
        //"<label>Amount</label>"

},
```

Comment: The problem is that Kendo hides the default editor when you use `k-radio`, so what user is doing is clicking in the label (even clicking in the styled radio). That somehow breaks the feature. Check this out: https://dojo.telerik.com/odoleFUP/3 I could not figure out how to fix it.

Comment: I appreciate your help.